# tor not working with sqlmap

Tags: proxy, tor, sqlmap

root@kali:~# sqlmap --tor --tor-type=SOCKS5 -u http://www.target.com/abc.php?cat=50

```
sqlmap/1.0-dev - automatic SQL injection and database takeover tool
http://sqlmap.org
```

[!] legal disclaimer: Usage of sqlmap for attacking targets without prior mutual consent is illegal. It is the end user's responsibility to obey all applicable local, state and federal laws. Developers assume no liability and are not responsible for any misuse or damage caused by this program

```
[*] starting at 14:18:00

[14:18:00] [WARNING] increasing default value for option '--time-sec' to 10 because switch '--tor' was provided
[14:18:00] [INFO] setting Tor SOCKS proxy settings
[14:18:00] [INFO] testing connection to the target URL
[14:18:00] [CRITICAL] unable to connect to the target URL or proxy. sqlmap is going to retry the request
[14:18:00] [WARNING] please make sure that you have Tor installed and running so you could successfully use switch '--tor' (e.g. 'https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tor')
[14:18:01] [CRITICAL] unable to connect to the target URL or proxy. sqlmap is going to retry the request
[14:18:02] [CRITICAL] unable to connect to the target URL or proxy. sqlmap is going to retry the request
[14:18:03] [CRITICAL] unable to connect to the target URL or proxy

[*] shutting down at 14:18:03
```

how to fix this ???

Answer (score 4):

You have to install tor `apt-get install tor` and then run `tor` in a terminal, after that you can do `sqlmap --tor --tor-type socks5 --tor-port=9050 --check-tor -u http://www.target.com/abc.php?cat=50` to execute with tor.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue the way that I solved it was to use proxychains and edit the proxychains conf file to route requests through tor. It is easy enough to do

I do not have kali open but you can find the file by opening the terminal and typing

```
locate proxychains.conf
```